# How can I check if a property exits in my object?

Tags: arrays, symfony, oop, object, properties

This is my object `fields`:

```
{#7139 ▼
  +"id": array:9 [▼
    "fieldName" => "id"
    "type" => "integer"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => null
    "unique" => false
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "id" => true
    "columnName" => "id"
  ]
  +"name": array:8 [▼
    "fieldName" => "name"
    "type" => "string"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => 255
    "unique" => false
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "columnName" => "name"
  ]
  +"unique_id": array:8 [▼
    "fieldName" => "unique_id"
    "type" => "string"
    "scale" => 0
    "length" => 10
    "unique" => true
    "nullable" => false
    "precision" => 0
    "columnName" => "unique_id"
  ]
  +"productgroup": array:20 [▼
    "fieldName" => "productgroup"
    "joinTable" => array:3 [▶]
    "targetEntity" => "App\Entity\Productgroup"
    "mappedBy" => null
    "inversedBy" => null
    "cascade" => []
    "orphanRemoval" => false
    "fetch" => 2
    "type" => 8
    "isOwningSide" => true
    "sourceEntity" => "App\Entity\Products"
    "isCascadeRemove" => false
    "isCascadePersist" => false
    "isCascadeRefresh" => false
    "isCascadeMerge" => false
    "isCascadeDetach" => false
    "joinTableColumns" => array:2 [▶]
    "isOnDeleteCascade" => true
    "relationToSourceKeyColumns" => array:1 [▶]
    "relationToTargetKeyColumns" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
}
```

I want to get the name of the object that contains `relationToSourceKeyColumns`

This is my approach:

```
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $ManyToMany = property_exists($field['fieldName'], 'relationToSourceKeyColumns');
      if($ManyToMany == true){
        $result = $field['fieldName'];
      }
    }
```

The result is:

```
""
```

but my expected result is:

```
"productgroup"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `property_exists` is for object (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php). In your structure search key is in array, maybe use `array_key_exists` (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: ah,this is the correct solution: `array_key_exists('relationToSourceKeyColumns', $field)`